# set session timeout after inactivity

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to redirect back to the home page when there is no activity.
However, i dont have a user login or the need to have one. However, i want to be able to redirect back to the home page when theres no activity.

I set this in the web.conf

```
<system.web>
<sessionState mode="InProc"  timeout="2">
```

then, i set this in the homepage

```
Session["UserId"] = 1;
```

I also tried this but the function doesnt even fire.

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CheckSession();
    }


    private void CheckSession()
    {
        if (Session["UserId"] == null)
        {
            Response.Redirect("KioskHome.aspx");
        }
    }
```

Could i use the global.asax file?

```
void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Code that runs when a new session is started

    }

    void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


    }
```

What is the simple solution? Thank you

Comment: This should answer your question http://stackoverflow.com/a/6210463/590177

Comment: Thats not my post and that solution doesnt help me. So why close my post?

Comment: If you want to check for a session timeout and then redirect then the code provided will work for you. The two questions both relate to a timeout redirect, that's why I provided a close vote. Perhaps explain why the solution doesn't help?

Comment: i tried both solution and its doing nothing.

Comment: You need to wait for the timeout period to elapse and then attempt to browse somewhere else, that's when the redirect code will run.

Comment: Ok, its working. I thought i automatically worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question, you want to redirect the user's browser if the user hasn't performed any action in some period of time.

In that case - server-side behaviour won't help you. The connection has already closed. The global.asax Session_end will fire when the session is ending, and there won't be a client connected at that time. 
Perhaps you should read more about the [ASP.NET Page Lifecycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx).

What you may want, however, is some form of client-side behavior such as Javascript, which after a specific timeout, can redirect the user. 
Note that there's a number of issues with this, including that a user may use multiple tabs, so knowing accurately when the session has timed out is difficult.